# How to extract quarters from dates?

Tags: r

Why doesn't the cut at "3 months" produce labels as expected?

```
 # create time series data
 everyday <- seq(from = as.Date('2014-1-1'), to = as.Date('2014-12-31'), by = 'day')

 # create a factor based on the quarter of the year an observation is in:
 qtrs <- cut(everyday, "3 months", labels = paste0('Q', 1:4))

 ## Error in cut.default(unclass(x), unclass(breaks), labels = labels, 
 ## right = right,  : 
 ##   lengths of 'breaks' and 'labels' differ
```

The cut is every 3 months, so that would create 4 Quarters and I'd expect to need 4 labels, but the error message suggests that the length of breaks and labels differs.

```
 qtrs <- cut(everyday, "3 months", labels = paste0('Q', 1:5))
 table(qtrs)
 ## qtrs
 ## Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4 Q5 
 ## 90 91 92 92  0
```

The fifth label Q5 seems to be needed and yet appears with a zero count.

The example is taken from "Data Manipulation with R" by Phil Spector,

http://www.springer.com/statistics/computational+statistics/book/978-0-387-74730-9

Comment: Perhaps the `quarters` function could be useful here?

Comment: Or even just use "quarters" instead of "3 months"?

Comment: Indeed `qtrs <- cut(everyday, "quarters", labels = paste0('Q', 1:4))` works, thanks! Does one of you want to answer this so we can close the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not answer your original question, but is a way to achieve (what I assume is) the same result, without `cut`. You may use the `quarters` function to extract the 'quarter' from a `Date` object:

```
table(quarters(everyday))
# Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4 
# 90 91 92 92
```